# Modifying key values in a json array file, and writing the changed values to that same file

Tags: java, gson

**I** **have** a json array in a file "test.json". the array contains the following:

```
    [
      {
        "txt": "this text is encrypted"
        "ft": "this text is encrypted",
        "Id": 2,
        "No": 2,
      },
      {
        "txt": "this text is encrypted"
        "ft": "this text is encrypted",
        "Id": 42,
        "No": 2,
      },
      {
        "txt": "this text is encrypted"
        "ft": "this text is encrypted",
        "Id": 12,
        "No": 24,
      },
      .
      .
      .
      . ~ 800 objects, each have the same signature 
      {
        "txt": "this text is encrypted"
        "ft": "this text is encrypted",
        "Id": 47,
        "No": 4,
      }

    ]
```

> **The task**

What I'm trying to do is, read the test.json , go through each key "txt" and "ft" of each object in the array separately (the values of these keys are encrypted and I already coded the method that decrypt these values) and pass these values separately to my decrypt() method which returns the decrypted string respectively, then overwrite the old encrypted values of each of these keys in the test.json file to the new decrypted values for all of the objects in the array.

> **What I'm trying to achieve**

*I'm facing difficulty in achieving the following correctly:*

- Access the "txt" and "ft" values of each object one at a time; two at an object.
- pass "txt" and "ft" values respectively to the decrypt() method.
- store the returned decrypted strings from the decrypt() method in a temp string variables respectively.
- Write those temp string vars to the file directly, thus overwriting the original values (that are encrypted) of the "txt" and "ft" with the new decrypted values.

> **My attempt**

```
final String JSON_PATH = "/test.json";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JSON_PATH));
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray arrayObj = parser.parse(br).getAsJsonArray();

for (JsonElement elm : arrayObj) {
            JsonObject burObj = elm.getAsJsonObject();
            String  temp_fn  ;  
            String  temp_txt  ; 
            String  _fn = burObj.get("ft").getAsString();
            String  _txt = burObj.get("txt").getAsString();
            temp_fn = Decrypt(_fn);
            temp_txt= Decrypt(_txt);
}
```

---

this is as far as I got before my brain stopped working, like **how could I write the decrypted string to proper value keys and overwrite them, while keeping the test.json file open for the for loop to go through the next object in the array and do the whole process again till it finishes.**

also I apologize for the quality of the code I have not coded in java in 5 years !

---

Answer (score 0):

Resave new json object to the file. Or this approach doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace message?

Answer (score 0):

If your objects all have the same signature, consider creating a class containing these fields:

```
public class Encrypted {
    String txt;
    String ft;
    @SerializedName("Id")
    int id;
    @SerializedName("No")
    int no;
}
```

Then read your JSON as follows:

```
Collection<Encrypted> data = new Gson().fromJson(new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename)), new TypeToken<Collection<Encrypted>>(){}.getType());
```

Iterate over the objects, change them accordingly (decryption) and save the

```
Collection<Encrypted> data;
```

to the JSON file again using:

```
new Gson().toJson(data, new FileWriter(filename));
```